# How do I prevent Android from going to sleep?

Tags: standby, sleep

I never want my Android tablet to go to sleep, can I prevent sleep mode?

Answer (score 33):

Depending on your tablet, you may have the option to set the screen timeout to "never" under **Settings > Display > Sleep**.

If you do not have this option, you can enable **Settings > Developer options > Stay awake**. This will keep your tablet awake *while it is charging*. This could be useful if your tablet does not support the "never" screen timeout.

*Note*: If you don't see Developer options in Settings, you may find them and Stay awake in one of these places:

- You may first need to unlock developer options, as described [here](https://www.greenbot.com/article/2457986/how-to-enable-developer-options-on-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html).
- Simply search for **Stay awake** in Settings.
- **Settings > About > Build number**. Developer options should appear after tapping the build number several times.
- **Settings > System > Advanced > Developer options**
- **Settings > About > Android version > Kernel version**

(Rowan) Note: Developer options are not always under Build number; they can be in other places such as Kernel version. The developers apparently try to hide them in various locations and I know this because I myself have found them in different locations on different devices.

Comment: `Settings > Developer options > Stay awake` worked for me

Comment: The above options are not available on my Sony Xperia running Android 13

Answer (score 8):

There is a stay awake option while charging. For the older Android Froyo 2.2, it can be found under:

```
Settings > Applications > Development > Stay awake
```

"Screen will never sleep while charging."

The same option is still present up to the current 8.1 version, but you first have to unlock developer options.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably prevent you tablet from sleeping using an automation app like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (paid) or [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) (free).

Here’s a automation “flow” for Automate to keep the screen and CPU awake, but you can easily modify it to only keep the CPU awake:
http://llamalab.com/automate/community/flows/374

Answer (score 0):

I use the app [Caffeine](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/sqcubes/caffeine/), and it works very good. It's free, and highly helpful. It's very small also (few kb).